# Using a VPN tunnel on a Cisco ASA to connect locations

Tags: cisco-asa, site-to-site-vpn

I am looking for some advise on how to connect some of our locations together, using a site-to-site VPN on our Cisco ASA 5515-X.
At the moment we have a 5515-X at our head office and a Cisco 887A router at each location that we want to connect to the ASA and establish the VPN.

I see the connection profiles on the ASA whilst viewing the settings through the Cisco ASDM GUI and it looks quite straight forward, I think I can work this part out but can anyone tell me if the 887A routers are capable of doing this as I cannot put an ASA in each location.

Also, to start my testing I was hoping to connect my home network to the VPN but I am using a Virgin Media Super Hub. I have read that all I need to do is enable IPSec, PPTP and Multicast pass through but where do I enter the reverse VPN settings? 
If this is not possible on a Super Hub, then there is a possibility of placing a 887A router on the inside of my LAN.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question is yes you can. In fact Cisco has a thread about it [here](https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/10846136/site-site-vpn-using-asa5520-and-cisco-887-adsl-router-atm-interface).

For your question about Virgin Media Super Hub, yes it is capable of doing a site to site VPN connection but there are a number of other users who appear to have had problems doing this. You can read about their issues [here](https://community.virginmedia.com/t5/Forum-Archive/How-do-I-set-up-VPN-with-the-Super-Hub-please/td-p/689161). You can create the VPN by clicking Network Connections -> Select your Connection -> Right Click -> Properties -> Securities Tab -> Choose the type of VPN.

Comment: Brilliant thank you! I will have a read through and report back.

Comment: Hi Becky, did this work? If it did, please feel free to make the answer as accepted so other people can find the answer too. Thanks!